# regex copy data from left notepad++ into right section

Tags: regex

I was looking at some regex but I was coming up short

I'm using Notepad++ for editing a lot of fields

Data looks like this

```
CmntStatus += row[""];
TcKey += row[""];
```

However , I want to copy the first value into the right quotes

End result:

```
   CmntStatus += row["CmntStatus "];
   TcKey += row["TcKey "];
```

I was trying

```
  ^1 += row["$1"];
```

Comment: Find what: `(^.*?)(\s.*?")("\];)`   ----  Replace with:  `$1$2$1$3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what: `^(.*) \+= row\[""\];`

Replace with: `(\1) += row["\1"];`